# FabricJs reset custom controls for a specific object

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am using the fabricjs extension - [fabricjs-customise-controls-extension](https://github.com/pixolith/fabricjs-customise-controls-extension) in my project. I am using the following code to set the controls for all objects:

```
fabric.Object.prototype.customiseCornerIcons({
    settings: {
        cornerSize: 40,
        cornerShape: 'circle',
        borderColor: "rgba(173,173,173,1)"
    },
    tl: {
        icon: '/images/icon/rotate-rounded.png'
    },
    tr: {
        icon: '/images/icon/resize-rounded.png'
    },
    br: {
        icon: '/images/icon/delete-rounded.png'
    }
});
```

I am able to change the icons of the custom controls for a specific object using the following code:

```
specificObject.customiseCornerIcons({
    settings: {
        cornerSize: 40,
        cornerShape: 'circle',
        borderColor: "rgba(173,173,173,1)"
    },
    tl: {
        icon: '/images/icon/resize-rounded.png'
    },
    tr: {
        icon: '/images/icon/resize-rounded.png'
    }
}, function () {
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Is it possible to remove the custom controls for a specific object and reset to the default fabric js controls?

JsFiddle URL: https://jsfiddle.net/arunnambissan/sffq2zc4/4/

Comment: As you have stated, if you add that then only it will applicable to an object. What do you mean by this  ***custom controls for a specific object*** ?

Comment: I have updated my question. Plese have a look.

Comment: Try `object.customiseCornerIcons()` don't pass any argument

Comment: I have tried that, but no use.

Comment: I can't replicate the issue as I am on mobile only now, can you make a fiddle?

Comment: @Durga I have added a code sample to a fiddle. Please check - https://jsfiddle.net/arunnambissan/sffq2zc4/4/

Comment: Raise a issue in their project. One thing I observed is all the time `cornerStrokeColor` is transparent. Thats why stroke is not visible and they never handled a situation where there is no image.